# Multithreading Keep threads active

Tags: python, multithreading

I am struggling with multi threading my code. I want to ALWAYS have 10 active threads, but I am not sure how.
Current code:

```
import threading
from random import randint
import os
import names
import random
import time

threads = 10

def f():
    print("my actual function is 200+ lines")
    return

for i in range(threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=f)
    t.start()
```

My current code starts 10 threads, but does not maintain them, keep active. Thank you for the help

edit: have also tried with `while True`, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your loops active, you should have a loop in your thread function as you said. But in this piece of code there is a return callback that will exit from your loop after print. You should write somethings like this:

```
def f():
    while True:
        print("my actual function is 200+ lines")
```

And if you want to manage your thread to stop sometimes, you should write a stop function and use a Boolean flag to control your while loop (instead of while True).

```
thread_status = True

def stopThread():
    thread_status = False
    
def f():
    while thread_status:
        print("my actual function is 200+ lines")
```

Comment: It just spams my log over and over with so much text. Are you please able to post my code with your examples in my code?

Comment: This is your code, I've just remove return statement, and added stop function. That printed logs are showing you that threads are actively running! This is just an example you should add other part of your code to it.